# The dark at the crux of a poem

Tags: riddle

The dark at the crux of a poem,
The bird of the saintly days of yore.
The brother without an eye in the genius,
The shadow that floats from the floor.
The last letter of the last word never spoken.
The first letter of an age which death had broken.

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.SE]. Is this your own creation?

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea what this could be, but my approach includes a lot of association and may very well be completely on the wrong track.

Alright, here goes nothing:

> The dark at the crux of a poem

> A lyric is a special type of poem. At its center (as a literal interpretation of the figurative *crux*) are the letters *yri*, which sound like *eerie*, if you read them out loud; something that might be associated with darkness.

> The bird of the saintly days of yore

> The *dove*, which famously brought the news of the receding flood to Noah on his ark (although, [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative#Composition), it may also have been a raven).

> The brother without an eye in the genius

> *Genius* without the i (which is what *eye* sounds like if we read it out loud) leaves us with *Genus*. While the brother genera to Homo, the human, are [technically, Pongo, Gorilla and Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape#Taxonomic_classification_and_phylogeny), I feel like *ape* should be close enough.

> The shadow that floats from the floor

> In [programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-), the *floor* function usually returns a *floating* point number that is equal to an integer, which means that any decimal place (its metaphorical *shadow*) would be a *0*.

> The first letter of an age which death had broken

> The Middle Ages, which [ended in a demographic collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_of_the_Late_Middle_Ages). The first letter is an *m*.

> The last letter of the last word never spoken

> The words never spoken in this riddle are the words I just tried to pry from its lines. The last one would be *Middle*, given that *Age* is indeed mentioned in the line above. The last letter is an *e*.

This leaves us with:

> eerie dove ape 0 e m

> Reading this out loud sounds like:
>
>  *a read of a poem*
>
>  which is what I just did.

Comment: I also really like the poem itself!